# If you apply for an IEC work permit with a letter of offer can you change jobs once you get there?

Tags: canada

I am applying for the IEC young professional work permit at the moment so that I can travel and work in Canada. What happens if I want to change jobs when I get out there, do I have to reapply for a different work permit? Or is the work permit open?

Answer (score 1):

[International Experience Canada (IEC)](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/work/iec/index.asp) provides youth with the opportunity to travel and work in Canada.

> **Can I change employers if I have an International Experience Canada work permit**?
>
> If you have a work permit under the Working Holiday category, you can change employers whenever you want or need to.
>
> Under the Young Professionals and International Co-op (Internship) categories, you can only [change your employer](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/work/extend/iec.asp) if you have a valid reason.